# Client or server has a null key while getting initial credentials when trying to authenticate to ApacheDS Kerberos

Tags: linux, authentication, kerberos, apacheds

I am running an instance of ApacheDS, and use it for Kerberos authentication. According to the documentation, the server should automatically generate `krb5Key` attributes on each LDAP entry for a user when created, however, this does not happen. Instead, no such elements exist, and when I try to use `kinit` to login, this happens:

```
[7597] 1583700137.226456: Received error from KDC: -1765328375/Client or server has a null key
kinit: Client or server has a null key while getting initial credentials
```

Some output was removed but it was all DNS/IP debug.

Is there any way to generate these keys otherwise, or somehow get ApacheDS to make them like its supposed to?